# JNI GetObjectClass with primitive type

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, jvmti

I have the following JNI/JVMTI code:

```
jfieldID field = ...;
jobject fieldValue = (*jni_env)->GetObjectField(jni_env, jObjectInstance, field);
jclass fieldClass = (*jni_env)->GetObjectClass(jni_env, fieldValue);
char* signature_ptr;
char* generic_ptr;
(*jvmti_env)->GetClassSignature(jvmti_env, fieldClass, &signature_ptr, &generic_ptr);
```

This code works as long *field* is a reference type (java.lang.Object and subtypes). If *field* is a primitive type, it will crash the JVM when it tries to execute *GetObjectClass*.

My question is: How can I use *field* and *fieldValue* to figure out if it is a primitive type and if it's a primitive type, which one (int, long, boolean etc.)?

I am new to JNI/JVMTI so if the answer is obvious, please bear with me.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you obtain `jfieldID field`? JNI `GetFieldID` function requires field name and signature, so usually, when getting `jfieldID`, you already know the type of the field.

Comment: There is a method in JVMTI GetClassFields which returns all the fields for a jclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's illegal to call `GetObjectField` with `jfieldID` which is not an object type. For primitive fields, you need to call one of the other `Get[Type]Field` functions, where `[Type]` is `Int`/`Long`/`Boolean`/etc.

Since you already have `jvmti_env`, the easiest way to find `jfieldID` type is to call JVM TI [GetFieldName](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#GetFieldName) function. Among other things, it returns the field signature, i.e. the type of the field.

The only problem is that `jfieldID` should always be accompanied with `jclass` - the holder of the field, since field IDs are relative to the particular class. Typically, when you get `jfieldID`, you already know its holder class. If not, in your case you have `jObjectInstance` - an object that has this field, so the holder class can be derived from the instance using JNI [GetObjectClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#getobjectclass) function.

```
jclass fieldHolder = (*jni_env)->GetObjectClass(jni_env, jObjectInstance);

char* name;
char* signature;
if ((*jvmti_env)->GetFieldName(jvmti_env, fieldHolder, field, &name, &signature, NULL) == 0) {

    switch (signature[0]) {
        case 'I':
            // int
            break;
        case 'J':
            // long
            break;
        ...
        case 'L':
            // object
            break;
        case '[':
            // array
            break;
    }

    (*jvmti_env)->Deallocate(jvmti_env, signature);
    (*jvmti_env)->Deallocate(jvmti_env, name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I saw and tried to use GetFieldName, but I misunderstood the documentation  of the jclass parameter which says *The class of the field to query*. I thought it was the class of the jfieldID and not the class of the instance that holds the field.